React useEffect() not executing before page render
I'm trying to pull postcode information and display it on my react app. The code so far looks as such:
const UKPar = () => {

    postcode = "SW1A2AA"
    const [ukPostcodeData, setUKPostcodeData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + postcode)
           .then((res) => res.json())
           .then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
              setUKPostcodeData(data);
           })
           .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err.message);
           });
    }, [postcode]);

    return(...)
}
export default UKPar;

This works fine and I can see that the data is displayed in the browser log as so:
{
    "status": 200,
    "result": {
        "postcode": "SW1A 2AA",
        "quality": 1,
        "eastings": 530047,
        "northings": 179951,
        "country": "England",
        "nhs_ha": "London",
        "longitude": -0.127695,
        "latitude": 51.50354,
        "european_electoral_region": "London",
        "primary_care_trust": "Westminster",
        "region": "London",
        "lsoa": "Westminster 018C",
        "msoa": "Westminster 018",
        "incode": "2AA",
        "outcode": "SW1A",
        "parliamentary_constituency": "Cities of London and Westminster",
        "parliamentary_constituency_2024": "Cities of London and Westminster",
        "admin_district": "Westminster",
        "parish": "Westminster, unparished area",
        "admin_county": null,
        "date_of_introduction": "198001",
        "admin_ward": "St James's",
        "ced": null,
        "ccg": "NHS North West London",
        "nuts": "Westminster",
        "pfa": "Metropolitan Police",
        "codes": {
            "admin_district": "E09000033",
            "admin_county": "E99999999",
            "admin_ward": "E05013806",
            "parish": "E43000236",
            "parliamentary_constituency": "E14000639",
            "parliamentary_constituency_2024": "E14001172",
            "ccg": "E38000256",
            "ccg_id": "W2U3Z",
            "ced": "E99999999",
            "nuts": "TLI32",
            "lsoa": "E01004736",
            "msoa": "E02000977",
            "lau2": "E09000033",
            "pfa": "E23000001"
        }
    }
}

The issue is when I try and display this information the browser throws an error saying "ukPostcodeData.result is undefined". I have have used the following code to try and display the information I need and other testing has shown that this should give me the correct result, however is causing errors when the HTML is rendered.
<td>{ukPostcodeData.result.parliamentary_constituency}</td>

I have tried using other methods to call the information needed from ukPostcodeData to see if this would fix the problem. I used:
const getConstituency = () => {
    return ukPostcodeData.result.parliamentary_constituency
}

...
return (
...
    <td>{getConstituency()}</td>
...
)


Use optional chaining ukPostcodeData?.result?.parliamentary_constituency to show nothing until the data is loaded.
